# How can I summarize a table based on the last day of the month

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have an input table in PowerBI like this:

| Date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 10/17/2022 | 4343 |
| 10/18/20222 | 3169 |
| 11/23/2022 | 4681 |
| 12/23/2022 | 6542 |
| 12/16/2022 | 534324 |
| 1/30/2023 | 4343 |
| 1/18/2023 | 35325 |

I want to create a 'Summary' Table using which just keep the row for the most recent date of each month.

Meaning the output is

| Date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 10/18/20222 | 3169 |
| 11/23/2022 | 4681 |
| 12/23/2022 | 6542 |
| 1/30/2023 | 4343 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Starting table:

[image]

Highlight date column and then add year and month from the ribbon.

[image]

[image]

Group by as follows.

[image]

[image]

Merge back to source and expand.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Vc3BDYAwDEPRXXKulMZOSpml6v5rQBWK4Ppk+Y8hVtUORQWkiNMps6T2rbR2ppqC77Z1S8VHWzi2Wtsa9y88XVkX85d7agsZRMicFw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, id = _t]),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}}, "en-US"),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type with Locale", "Year", each Date.Year([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Year", "Month", each Date.Month([Date]), Int64.Type),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Month", {"Year", "Month"}, {{"Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Year", "Month"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"Date"}, #"Changed Type with Locale", {"Date"}, "Removed Columns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Removed Columns" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Removed Columns", {"id"}, {"id"})
in
    #"Expanded Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add two columns in table:

   Month = month([Date])

   Recent date = maxx(filter('Table',[Month]=earlier('table'[month])),'Table'[Date])
   [image]
2. create new table with formula:

   New table = values('table'[recent date])

[image]
3. set relationship between two tables(one to one with both cross filter direction):
[image]

4. create new column in new table:

   id = related('Table'[id])
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

And another method:

- Add a column with the End of Month Date
- Add a column with the difference between the stated date and the end of month.
- Group by End of Month and select row with the minimum difference

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"id", Int64.Type}}),

//add columns with End of Month Date and
// Days until end of Month
    #"Add End Of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "EOM", each Date.EndOfMonth([Date]), type date),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add End Of Month", "Days to EOM", each Duration.Days([EOM]-[Date])),

//Group by EOM and select by minimum Days to EOM
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"EOM"}, {
        {"Date", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t,  each [Days to EOM]= List.Min(t[Days to EOM])),
            type table[Date=date, id=Int64.Type]}
        }),

//Remove unneeded columns and expand the tables
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"EOM"}),
    #"Expanded Date" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Date", {"Date", "id"})
in
    #"Expanded Date"
```

[image]